# pointing to element before array start in C99

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c99

I have an array of integers:

```
int* counters = (int *) calloc(N, sizeof(int));
```

that must be indexed using one based indexes e.g. first element has index 1, second element has index 2, etc. Since performance was very important I decided to use a trick:

```
int* oneIndexedCounters = counters - 1;
```

that allow me to use one based indexing without subtracting 1 from indexes:

```
// A[i] - contains one based indexes
for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
    oneIndexedCounters[A[i]] += B[i]; // many times in code
    // some other operations on oneIndexedCounters
}
```

insted of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
    counters[A[i]-1] += B[i];
    // ...
}
```

`counters` array is returned by my function so I couldn't allocate dummy element at array beginning.

Is pointing one element before array valid (for example when array is on memory page boundary) when you are not dereferencing that pointer?
Or is there other solution that is less tricky and gives good performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is pointing one element before array valid (for example when array is on memory page boundary) when you are not dereferencing that pointer?

No, it's not valid.

```
int* oneIndexedCounters = counters - 1;
```

`counters - 1` does not point to a valid object, the operation invokes undefined behavior.

> (C99, 6.5.6p8) "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of
>           the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>           object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>           behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

As [ouah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29329448/827263) correctly states, subtracting 1 from a pointer to the initial element of an array object has undefined behavior -- even if you don't dereference it. (As I recall, some editions of "Numeric Recipes in C" use this technique to emulate Fortran array semantics. It can "work" if you're "lucky.)

There is an alternative: Allocate an array 1 element longer than you need, and access its elements via a pointer to the 2nd element (element 1).

For example:

```
int *counters = calloc(N+1, sizeof(*counters));
```

You can then safely access `counters[1]` through `counters[N]`, just as if you had a 1-based array. The only drawback is that you have an additional element 0 that you never use. If it's an array of some relatively small type, that shouldn't matter.

A digression on `calloc`:

Strictly speaking, `calloc()` isn't guaranteed to initialize floating-point objects to `0.0`, or pointers to `NULL`. It is practically guaranteed to initialize integers to `0`; this guarantee was made explicit in a post-C99 Technical Corrigendum and in C11. If you happen to know that your system represents floating-point `0.0` and null pointers as all-bits-zero, it's probably ok to use `calloc` -- but I'd add a comment making the assumption explicit. Systems that *don't* use all-bits-zero for `0.0` and `NULL` are rare. It's up to you to decide how important 100% portability is.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that because I must return allocated array to external code that must `free` it at some point. And this code (that I have no control over) assumes it is zero indexed (confusing? it is).

Comment: @csharpfolk: Yes, it is confusing. You need to treat it as 1-based, but the caller to which you return the allocated array needs to treat it as 0-based? I think you need to add some more details to the question.

Comment: To be more precise array is zero based in my and external code (first element is always at index 0), but algorithm that I use assume that arrays are 1-based, so I have to write `array[someComplicatedExpr-1]` in several places to translate 1-based indexing into 0-based indexing. I just need a  way to skip subtract 1 part - first I tried to modify `array` pointer but as @ouah pointed out it triggers undefined behavior.